# Remove Vowels from string using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to remove vowels from a string of 2D array using pointers. I'm able to detect the vowels via their ASCII values, but the strings are not getting updated.

This section of the code **cannot** change.

```
void remove_vowel(char strings[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH])
```

Where is my code going wrong?

**Updated code:**

```
void remove_vowel(char strings[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH])
    {
        // loop through each row, starting intitally points to last element
        for (char(*p)[STRING_LENGTH] = strings; p != strings + NUM_STRINGS; ++p) {
            // variable q points to the first element       
            for (char *q = *p; q != *p + STRING_LENGTH; ++q) {

                if (*q != 'a' && *q != 'e' && *q != 'i' && *q != 'o' && *q != 'u') {
                    //printf("%c",*q);          
                    *q = *q;
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

I was able to re-write the code using the solution listed below. Thanks for the help everyone!

**Solution**

```
void remove_vowel(char strings[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH])
    {
        // store the array in a pointer
        char(*wordHolder)[STRING_LENGTH] = strings; 

        // loop through each row
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
        {
            // assign worl
            char *letter = *wordHolder;
            char *dest = *wordHolder;

            // check if null character
            while (*letter != '\0') {
                // check for vowels
                if (*letter != 'a' && *letter != 'e' && *letter != 'i' && *letter != 'o' && *letter != 'u') {
                    // assign non-vowel letter to destination
                    *dest++ = *letter;
                } 
                // move to next letter
                letter++;

            }
            // add null pointer to end of destination
            *dest = '\0';

            // increment pointer position to next word
            wordHolder++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `*q = *q;` is essentialy a NOP. Did you mean `*q = *p;`? Also this looks strange: `char *q = *p`.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers.  If you want to specify a character use the character like `'a'` instead.

Comment: You have an array of strings. (Which in turn are character arrays). Why don't you partition the problem. Create a function, which will do this for one string, and then use that in another function, which will loop through the main array?

Comment: @NathanOliver Those were the ASCII values of vowels, but I have replaced. That part seems to be working, it's the strings are not updated after check.

Comment: @cosmoo Yeah it was not your problem but it is an issue.  It makes your code a lot clearer and more correct using character literals than magic numbers.  If the code ever moved to a non ascii character set then it could break if you use the ascii values.

Comment: @NathanOliver k, I see, that makes sense. The code is certainly working and recognizing each character, my issue seems to be [*q = *q] as mentioned in comment 1.

Comment: @Dan This is C++ and function definition cannot change on this instance, the issue lies within the second for loop here.

Comment: @cosmoo Could you provide input and expected output?

Comment: If you have updated your real code please [edit] code in the question too.

Comment: @JonathanMee Sure. Inputs are as follows: apple, pineapple, coconut, orange, banana. Output should be ppl, pnppl, ccnt, rng, bnn.

Comment: Avoid pointer arithmetic, indices are easer for everyone.

Comment: @n.m. Certainly, indices are far simpler, though pointers are required in this instance.

Comment: your way of writing code makes it hard in debugging by anyone or you. for simplicity make a function called `remove_vowels` and pass it the `2d_array` by reference so it get updated when you remove vowels from it. `void remove_vowels(&array)`

Comment: What have you tested so far? Is the parameter correctly changed at the end of the function? Can you tell us where the error happens by the status that your debugger tells you?

Comment: @Aziuth There are no errors at all when I run the program. It's working, strings are just not updated once checked for vowels. Basically the print function shows the code is checking for vowels, but the final output is not being set.

Comment: Again: Check where the error happens. That is your job, not ours. Use a debugger. "There are no errors at all when I run the program" - yes, there are, if there weren't, you had no question. An error is when something happens in a way it shouldn't. Not necessarily something that ends your program. Use a debugger and see and which point in execution the current status is not as it should be. Separating the function in sub-functions as several people proposed helps with that.

Comment: @cosmoo What are you hoping that `*q = *q` will do? Even if correcting that solves your problem I'd still recommend that you go with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42207946/2642059) though.

Comment: @n.m. I agree that indices are easier, but I don't know that it follows that we should avoid pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider a C language equivalent.

In the C language you need to treat the text as an array.  With an array, when you *erase* a slot, you need to move the remaining items to overwrite the erased slot.

Let's begin there.

```
void dont_copy_vowels(char text_array[STRING_LENGTH])
{
   char * p_source = &text_array[0];
    char * p_destination = &text_array[0];
    const unsigned int length = strlen(text_array);
    while (*p_source != '\0')
    {
      static const char vowels[] = "aeiou";
      if (strchr(vowels, *p_source) != NULL)
      {
        ++p_source;
        continue; // don't copy vowels.
      }
      // Copy the letter or symbol.
      *p_destination++ = *p_source++;
    }
    *p_destination = '\0';
}
```

Since you are using an array of C-Style strings, you will need to place the above code in a loop:

```
for (unsigned int string_index = 0;
     string_index < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS;
     ++string_index)
{
  dont_copy_vowels(strings[string_index]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you should separate your existing `remove_vowel()` routine into (at least) **three** separate functions:

```
void remove_vowel(std::string& s)
{
...
}

void remove_vowel(std::vector<std::string>& strings)
{
    for(auto&& s : strings)
       remove_vowel(s);
}
void remove_vowel(char strings[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH]) // can't change this signature
{
    ...
}
```

Now your problem is reduced to two (or three) almost entirely unrelated pieces:

- removing vowels from a single `std::string`
- converting from a C-style array to C++
- (maybe: converting from C++ back to a C-style array)

Answer (score 2):

**This question has changed over time, originally it was asked against [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). I'm leaving it here for historical purposes, but it is not applicable to the newly targeted [c](/questions/tagged/c)**

---

[`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) should solve your problems, in which:

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the container is unchanged.

You could leverage `remove_if` like this:

```
void removeVowel(char strings[][STRING_LENGTH]) {
    for (auto p = strings; p != next(strings, NUM_STRINGS); ++p) {
        remove_if(begin(*p), end(*p), [vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"s](const auto& i){return vowels.find(i) != string::npos;});
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/12ch84)

This very simple solution requires that you're `char[]` elements are `'\0'` terminated. `remove_if` is simply moving all the vowel characters past the `'\0'` character where they are ignored. This may not be a viable solution if:

1. You are using a `char[]` that is not `'\0'` terminated, this is a very bad design decision, but if you're there let's discuss a workaround in the comments
2. `STRING_LENGTH` is very large; `remove_if` searches `STRING_LENGTH` elements each time so if you're string is much shorter than your containing array consider using `next(*p, strlen(*p) + 1)` instead of `end(*p)`

---

Comment on the `strings` parameter, for C++ function parameters:

> If the type is "array of `T`" or "array of unknown bound of `T`", it is replaced by the type "pointer to `T`" <sup>[[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list)]</sup>

So any value value in the major dimension of your array is discarded and treated as the parameter is converted to be treated as a pointer. Thus you'll see in my code an other code that the major dimension of array function parameters is left unpopulated, because it places no requirement on the actual size of array passed and may thereby create confusion, when an array with a different major dimension is accepted without warning.

Having waxed eloquent on that, you'll notice that all non-major dimensions in my code and other code *will* be populated. This is on account of the fact:

> A multidimensional array is very similar to a conventional array. Multidimensional arrays are stored as a continuous sequence of objects of the same type, just as an array is. The important thing to note are the numbers that define how large to make each dimension. Because of this it is not possible to pass a multidimensional array without also providing the length of its dimensions <sup>[[source](http://en.cppreference.com/book/arrays#Multidimensional_arrays)]</sup>

Thus, you'll notice that we *can* call `begin(*p)` and `end(*p)` but never <strike>`begin(strings)`</strike> or <strike>`end(strings)`</strike>.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you writing more "C++-like" code.

```
#include <string>  // needed for string container
#include <vector>  // needed for vector container

// This function removes all vowels from a std::string
std::string removeVowels(std::string input) {
    std::vector<std::string> vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}; // create and initilise a dynamic array with all vowels, that should be filtered
    // Iterate over all vowels
    for(const std::string vowel : vowels) {
        // Get first position of the appearance of the vowel,
        // exit if none are found
        while(auto pos = input.find(vowel) != std::string::npos) {
            // replace vowel with empty string
            input.erase(pos, vowel.size());
        }
    }
    // return our result
    return input;
};
```

I compiled and tested this example.

I let you write the function, that takes a 2d array of strings and using this function. Consider using std::vector over c-style arrays.

Comment: Rather than using `replace`, you may want to use `erase`.  I think `erase` would be more readable.